# Terraform: Providing list input values from command line?

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to provide list values from the command line?  There is variable merging for maps, but it doesn't seem to be working for lists.  I was hoping for something like, but no luck...  Thanks

```
terraform apply -var "listvar=abc1" -var "listvar=abc2"
```

or possibly

```
terraform apply -var "listvar=[abc1, abc2]"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to get this to work as follow:

1) Your variable file should reflect as follow:

```
 variable "listvar" {
      description = "some varaible to list"
      type = "list"
    }
```

2) Then run the apply command as exactly as follow:

`terraform apply -var 'listvar=["abc1", "abc2", "abc3"]'`

I hope that helps

https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html

Comment: No need to define the variable `listvar` as an empty value in tfvars file, if you  define it in `apply` command with option `-var`

Comment: @BMW, yes that is correct. Amended to reflect the two steps

Answer (score 1):

If anyone came here trying to figure out why this doesn't work with terragrunt; you need to escape the quotes:

```
terragrunt apply -var 'listvar=[\"abc1\", \"abc2\", \"abc3\"]'
```