# How do I pass a list as an argument?

Tags: terraform

This solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439904/terraform-providing-list-input-values-from-command-line) did not work for me.

```
// my tf file:
variable "myvar" {type = "list"}

module "my-module" {
  blah = "${var.myvar}"
  source = "path/to/module"
}
```

Various command line attempts:

```
terraform plan -var myvar="zzzz"
should be type list, got string

terraform plan -var myvar=["zzzz"]
invalid value "myvar=[zzzz]" for flag -var: Cannot parse value for variable ("[zzzz]") as valid HCL: At 1:6: unexpected token while parsing list: IDENT

terraform plan -var 'myvar=["zzzz"]'
invalid value "myvar=[zzzz]" for flag -var: Cannot parse value for variable ("[zzzz]") as valid HCL: At 1:6: unexpected token while parsing list: IDENT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange.

I used the following `main.tf`

```
variable "test" {
    type = "list"
}
```

and running:

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.11.1

$ terraform plan -var 'test=["vvv"]'
```

completed successfully.

It could be that there is an incorrect `IDENT` somewhere else in your file/module. Please try running the following command to validate everything except unset variables:

```
$ terraform validate -check-variables=false
```