# Terraform . How to pass multiple values in command line using list (string) in variable.tf file?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a simple main and variable files for deploying webapp for containers in Azure.

But I would like that terraform plan uses variables from the command line to choose names like follows:

```
terraform plan -var resource_group_name=my-rg
```

This worked perfectly commenting the name of the default value for the RG like this.

main.tf

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "my-rg" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}
```

variable.tf

```
variable "resource_group_name" {

    
#    default = "Search-API"

}
```

But if I want to do the same for a list string I don´t know how to do it. I want to be able to do something that If I put 2 names 2 webapps are going to be created, if I put 3, 3 webapps and so.

I tried with this (also commenting default value) :

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "azure-webapp" {
  count = length(var.webapp_server_name)
  name  = var.webapp_server_name[count.index]
```

variable.tf

```
variable "webapp_server_name" {
  
    description = "Create Webapp with following names"
    type        = list(string)
    #default     = ["webapp-a", "webapp-b", "webapp-c"]
```

But I´m getting:

```
 terraform plan -var webapp_server_name=webapp-a

Error: Variables not allowed

  on <value for var.webapp_server_name> line 1:
  (source code not available)

Variables may not be used here.
```

I also tried with empty string like:

```
variable "webapp_server_name" {
  
    description = "Create Webapp with following names"
    type        = list(string)
    default     = []
}
```

Is there a way to do such a thing with terraform? to define an empty list and pass values (one, two, or more) from command?

thanks

---

UPDATE
Tried like this, following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439904/terraform-providing-list-input-values-from-command-line) but now is asking to put the value even though I´m passing it through command line

```
terraform plan -var 'listvar=["webapp-a"]'

var.webapp_server_name
  Create Webapp with following names

  Enter a value:
```

Comment: For non-String type variable inputs with the CLI, I believe you have to pass the values as JSON-formatted.

Comment: just tried differently, check updated question. It also ask for a value

Comment: Your variable is named `webapp_server_name` and not `listvar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a variable declaration:

```
variable "webapp_server_name" {
  
    description = "Create Webapp with following names"
    type        = list(string)
    #default     = ["webapp-a", "webapp-b", "webapp-c"]
}
```

You could use it like this with `\` to escape the quotes`"`.

```
terraform plan -var 'webapp_server_name=[\"webapp-a\", \"webapp-b\", \"webapp-c\"]'
```

For example, it worked with using the latest terraform provider version `Terraform v0.13.4`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in the variable from the command line with `-var webapp_server_name=webapp-a` you are passing it in as a string.

But you've defined the variable as a list. So based on [the docs](http://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line) you'll want the command line to look something like:

```
terraform plan -var='webapp_server_name=["webapp-a"]'
```

Comment: that didn´t work. Tried different approach reading othter post with other result. check updated question.-