# Terraform list(string) variable in BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: terraform, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am deploying Terraform code through BitBucket pipelines. I am trying to integrate a list of string variables as a repository variable for the BitBucket pipeline. Below is the variable:

```
variable "ec2_instance" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["instance1", "instance2", "instance3"]
}
```

In the Bitbucket pipeline the variable is defined as a repository variable and is also specified within the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` as `terraform apply -var ec2_instance=$EC2_INSTANCE`

The blocker I am facing is the pipeline is unsuccessful. The output of the `terraform apply` command is

`Too many command line arguments. Configuration path expected.`

If I remove the `ec2_instance` repository variable, the pipeline then succeeds. I believe the issue lies within only string variables are able to used as a repository variable. Any advice on how to integrate a list(string) variable, would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly is `$EC2_INSTANCE`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64325392/11715259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running Terraform through a shell you will need to use quoting and escaping to make sure that the data you provide will be processed by Terraform rather than by the shell itself.

For a variable of `list(string)`, Terraform expects `-var` to contain a literal-only Terraform language expression which produces a list of strings, which inevitably means that it will contain some quote and bracket characters and it will often also contain *space* characters which a shell would understand as separators between arguments.

If your pipeline YAML is describing a shell script that will be run by a Unix-style shell such as Bash, you can avoid misinterpretation of space characters in your variable value by writing the reference to the variable wrapped in quotes, like this:

```
terraform apply -var ec2_instance="$EC2_INSTANCE"
```

Using double quotes `"` means that the shell will still search for interpolation sequences like `$EC2_INSTANCE` and expand them, but the result of that expansion will be treated as all part of the same argument even if it contains spaces.

Setting the `EC2_INSTANCE` variable's value can also be challenging, because the bracket and quote characters might be interpreted by the shell or YAML parser that you're setting the values through. Terraform is expecting the result (after all evaluation by the shell) to appear like this:

```
ec2_instance=["a", "b", "c"]
```

If you set `EC2_INSTANCE` inside a shell script then you can wrap the entire value in single quotes `'` to make the shell take it fully literally, without even trying to interpolate variables. The only character that's special inside single quotes is the single quote character itself, marking the end of the quoted portion:

```
export EC2_INSTANCE='["a", "b", "c"]'
```

If you are setting this environment variable in a YAML file, a web UI, an API, or similar then you will need to determine whether that intermediary has any escaping rules of its own which you must take into account.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This worked perfectly. I tried doing the same thing with a map(string) variable, but am getting a blocker when using the approach you mentioned above. Is there a different way for the pipeline to read a map of strings?